# Magento 2 Enterprise Edition - Need to run app:config:import every time in centralized database

Tags: magento2, database, magento-enterprise, magento-enterprise-2

I am working in centralized database in Magento 2 Enterprise Edition, Every time someone changes anything (even from admin configuration)

**I need to run `app:config:import` everytime if anythings changed**

---

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The configuration
>   file has changed. Run app:config:import or setup:upgrade command to
>   synchronize configuration.
>
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The
>   configuration file has changed. Run app:config:import or setup:upgrade
>   command to synchronize configuration.